# Navigating to /_ah/admin on localhost yields unknown 404 error

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I'm currently porting my GAE app to Python 2.7 and have come across some exciting things that I've slowly been able to figure out one at a time (Hello, aliased simplejson library!).  However, I'm currently at a loss to explain this particular issue.

Whenever I navigate to the Admin Console (http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin), I get a 404 page.  This is strange in itself (This was working just fine before), but it also isn't my custom 404 page.  This makes me think this is based on the built-in handlers, but I'm not sure what could be the cause.

Other fun facts:

- There's no attempts to handle /_ah/.* in my app.yaml or elsewhere
- Nothing has changed in my app.yaml aside from the usual script-to-WSGI handler stuff
- No usage of Federated Logins
- Over time I've turned on almost all of the builtins
- The app deploys correctly and without issue
- I'm using the GAE Launcher on OSX (Minor, but it does have some odd quirks about it)

*Update*

It's probably easier just to show the console logs of what is coming out.  This is after the app has fully started and I have attempted to navigate to the admin page twice (The IO Error is cute, and only happens the initial time):

```
[Master] [dev_appserver_multiprocess.py:650] INFO Running application mygaeapp on port 8081: http://localhost:8081
[Master] [dev_appserver_multiprocess.py:652] INFO Admin console is available at: http://localhost:8081/_ah/admin
[Master] [dev_appserver_multiprocess.py:901] DEBUG balancer to port 9000
[App Instance] [0] [py_zipimport.py:139] WARNING Can't open zipfile /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/slimmer-0.1.30-py2.7.egg: IOError: [Errno 13] file not accessible: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/slimmer-0.1.30-py2.7.egg'
[App Instance] [0] [py_zipimport.py:139] WARNING Can't open zipfile /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/NoseGAE-0.2.0-py2.7.egg: IOError: [Errno 13] file not accessible: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/NoseGAE-0.2.0-py2.7.egg'
[App Instance] [0] [recording.py:372] INFO Saved; key: __appstats__:012400, part: 67 bytes, full: 8780 bytes, overhead: 0.000 + 0.007; link: http://localhost:8081/_ah/stats/details?time=1331638312442
[App Instance] [0] [dev_appserver.py:2865] INFO "GET /_ah/admin HTTP/1.1" 404 -
[Master] [dev_appserver_multiprocess.py:901] DEBUG balancer to port 9000
[App Instance] [0] [recording.py:372] INFO Saved; key: __appstats__:020100, part: 67 bytes, full: 9196 bytes, overhead: 0.000 + 0.007; link: http://localhost:8081/_ah/stats/details?time=1331638320129
[App Instance] [0] [dev_appserver.py:2865] INFO "GET /_ah/admin HTTP/1.1" 404 -
[Master] [dev_appserver_multiprocess.py:901] DEBUG balancer to port 9000
```

Comment: Is the server logging the /_ah/admin request that's failing?  I assume other requests to the app on that port are succeeding?

Comment: Yes, but not as a 404.  It's indistinguishable from any other successful page.  Other requests on the port do succeed.

Our 404 handler is pretty distinct as it logs information at an exception level as part of the page render.

Comment: The _ah/admin uses the django template library.  Do you have any references to django in your app?  I've seen some people report errors, often from having the wrong version of django set up.

Comment: I do, actually.  However, I did set it up under 'libraries' to use django 1.2.  Mostly it's for the email regex and maybe a few other things.  The one thing it isn't being used for is templates (That's currently Mako)

Comment: Also, apologies Dan.  When I meant 'not as a 404' I meant one that I'm not used to.  The error code is definitely a 404 as shown in the log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally tracked this down to something that works perfectly fine in Python 2.5, but breaks on Python 2.7 with dev_appserver only.

To turn maintenance mode on and off, we reassign the routes in the WSGI instance to point to a new set of URLs by changing the `app.router` field directly.  Disabling this code path by checking the app version allows `/_ah/admin` to work correctly.

Answer (score 7):

In case you found this answer and you're using [App Engine SDK 1.7.6](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/old_devserver) or higher, the default URL has changed from `localhost:8080/_ah/admin` to `localhost:8000`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem due to the fact that I defined a URL filter in my `web.xml` file:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.example.MyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The filter class, `MyFilter`, has a `doFilter` method as below:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    String path = req.getRequestURI().substring(req.getContextPath().length());

    if (path.equals("/")) { // Welcome path
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/res/index").forward(request, response);
    } else if (path.startsWith("/static") || path.startsWith("/_ah")) { 
        // Static content or internal and admin stuff
        chain.doFilter(request, response); // Goes to default servlet.
    } else { // Jersey servlet controller
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/res" + path).forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

The part in the code above reading `|| path.startsWith("/_ah")` solved my problem, because the filter must allow paths starting with `/_ah` to go through unchanged.

I needed the filter so that Jersey could work without all my REST paths being prepended with `/res` or whatever is specified in `web.xml`.